What is the significance of a nuchal cord in Sanatan Dharma?
In Sanatan Dharma, certain birth-related occurrences are often seen as significant or indicative of potential events. I recently came across the concept of a nuchal cord (where the umbilical cord is wrapped around a baby’s neck) and wondered if this holds any significance in the scriptures of Sanatan Dharma.
Medically, it is understood that there is no way to prevent a nuchal cord, and it is never caused by anything the mother has done. This suggests that it may be dependent on the jiva being born, potentially carrying some spiritual significance. I am interested in learning whether this phenomenon is interpreted, symbolized, or referenced in the scriptures.
